# Problems with linking to views in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm in the process of setting up my views in Django, but I'm confused about how to link it to my `pageOne.html` page so it shows that instead of the "Welcome" page. Currently, when I run the server using `python manage.py runserver 127.0.0.2:8001` I get an error message that says "Template Does Not Exist at" `pageOne.html`.

I've set

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static", "templates"))
```

I've also tried

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = ('/Users/andrewnguyen/Desktop/Websites/gale/python/techExercise/templates',)
```

but that hasn't really worked either.

Update:

Here's a screenshot. I imagine that my error is somewhere in my urls, settings or views.py. I've changed the path to my TEMPLATE_DIRS as mentioned in the comment below. That did not work. I've included an image of my file structure on Imgur: http://imgur.com/kR1xcGJ

Comment: Can you share your views, url and project directory sturture here.

Comment: What is "static" doing there? Your templates are not in your static directory.

Comment: And please show the full traceback, as that will show exactly where it is looking.

Comment: what is the location of `pageOne.html` ?

Comment: Here's a screenshot. I imagine that my error is somewhere in my urls, settings or views.py. I've changed the path to my TEMPLATE_DIRS as mentioned in the comment below. That did not work. I've included an image of my file structure on Imgur: http://imgur.com/kR1xcGJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `TEMPLATE_DIRS` settings should look like this:

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates"),
)
```

**Update**

After looking at that screenshot you posted, I can say you've made a lot of mistakes.

1. The `templates` folder is inside the `static` folder.

   Move the `templates` folder out of the `static` folder.
2. There's a mistake in the `return` statement of your view.

It should look like this:

```
return render(request, 'pageOne.html')
```

There's no need to prepend `/static/templates/` to the template name. Django automatically looks for templates in your settings' `TEMPLATE_DIRS` path.

And finally, nothing you're doing is very difficult. All these mistakes are caused by ignorance, since everything is mentioned elaborately in the docs. Please read them carefully.

Comment: File structure was definitely the problem. Thanks for taking the time to answer my question, this is the very first time I've touched Django.